# Repeatscout installation problem

Tags: software-installation

I've installed Repeatscout from https://bix.ucsd.edu/repeatscout/.
I've also installed TRF and nseg required by the program. 
I followed the steps:

```
build_lmer_table -l 16 -sequence ~/file_fasta/od_1000.fa -freq od_1000.freq
```

```
 RepeatScout -sequence od_1000.fa -output od_1000_repeats.fa -freq od_1000.freq -l 16
```

and the I put this command:

```
cat od_1000_repeats.fa| filter-stage-1.prl >od_1000_repeats_filt1.fa
```

but this message appears:

```
bash: filter-stage-1.prl: command not found...
```

Why? It is all correctly installed, I can't understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the RepeatScout directory you need to execute the Perl script with a `./` prefix, like so.

```
cat od_1000_repeats.fa | ./filter-stage-1.prl > od_1000_repeats_filt1.fa
```

If you're not in the RepeatScout directory, you need to provide the full relative or absolute path when executing the script. Alternatively, you can put the RepeatScout directory in your `$PATH` environmental variable.

These are all standard UNIX/Linux concepts that many bioinformaticians take for granted, for better and for worse. If you're lost in all the terminology, a crash course in UNIX basics is probably where you would want to start.

Comment: I installed repeatscout on my PC, I created the Repeatscout directory and It worked without errors. The problem is that it can't execute a file larger more than 800 mb in a 16 gb ram of my pc. So I had to use the cluster but I don't know where is the Repeatscout directory.(If I put "locate Repeatscout" I don't find it). I would to find the path to check if all the programs are correctly installed..

Comment: It sounds like you need to get some help from your system administrator.